# 20.04 ubuntu lsb_release segfault python3.8

Tags: 20.04, python3, segmentation-fault

I am getting frequent error reports in the journal.

```
kernel: python3[717001]: segfault at 6f000020 ip 00000000005b676e sp 00007ffd3c41da38 error 4 in python3.8[423000+28d000]
```

Where the line numbers and memory addresses, even that error code may be different.

I don't see a bug report for this so it may be just me.

Any ideas on this one?

Comment: You can sort out the crash files in `/var/crash` to get some clues.